# Difference in voltage level using different probes

Tags: signal, oscilloscope, probe

I have used an active probe and a passive probe to do the same measurement at the same site. However, the active probe has measured a lower voltage than the passive probe under DC coupling measurement.

I would like to know in detail why there is such a drop.

Vpp: 3.3 V measured by keysight N2873A with 10:1 attenuation with E2697A high impedance adaptor.
Vpp: 2.7 V measured by active soldered on differential probe N5382A connect to keysight adaptor probe 1169B.

Oscilloscope used is Agilent Infiinium DSO80604B 6 GHz 40 Gsamples/s. The signal seems to be the same for other scopes.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The pulse width is about 270ms on one measurement whilst ~160us on another. Also sampling frequencies are different on both. Try to take the measurement for the same pulse-width signal and with the same time/div and sampling rate settings for a fair comparison because the scope's internal programmable gain might be different for different conditions *(my Le Croy shows higher measurements as time/div increases especially for high-frequency signals)*. Also, 1) did you change the probes while the scope is on? 2) if yes to 1 then did the scope calibrate the channel after probe replacement?

Comment: YH CasperL - This looks similar to one of your previous questions [here](/q/678045) where you were asked to supply more information, but did not do so. Your question was "closed" by community voting, waiting for you to edit that question and add details. || Asking a new question with *some* more details about a previous question, is not the appropriate response on Stack Exchange. Instead the requested details should be added by editing *that* question. || You received a plausible answer on that question. Does that answer apply here? Did you consider it? Again, please add the schematic. Thanks.

Comment: I just reupdated the plots, why is it closed. Schematic is confidential, so how do I add it?

Comment: @YHCasperL - (a) You did not address all the points in my previous comment. It may start to annoy people who carefully analyse your posts and attempt to help you to improve them, but where some points are ignored. (b) "*why is it closed*" Your earlier question is "[closed](/help/closed-questions)" (that state used to be called "on hold") waiting for you to edit it & add the requested details. Then it would be considered for reopening. (c) "*Schematic is confidential*" So you will have a problem getting help about signals on any public forum, if you can't upload at least the relevant part :(

Comment: okay noted, let me refine this post in a while. meanwhile, could you help to remove the last post, understood it is repeated and would want to start fresh on this post as the last post was unanswered. thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question needs a schematic {...}. Furthermore, the question *should* be an edit to a previous closed question {...}. [Edited by a moderator to remove unneeded parts.]

Comment: @YHCasperL - "*could you help to remove the last post*" Do you mean [this one I previously linked](/q/678045), although that is not your last post? "*understood it is repeated and would want to start fresh on this post as the last post was unanswered*" That linked post *did* get a relevant answer which might be the explanation of that question (and therefore apply here too), so I'm confused what you mean by "unanswered". || And while I've been typing, this question received a similar answer too. || I will *consider* merging questions (it's risky), if you confirm what you meant by "last post".

Answer (score 3):

The difference is probably because the [Keysight 1169B](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/product/1169B/infiniimax-ii-series-probe-amplifier-12-ghz.html) has an input impedance of 50k ohm while the [E2697A](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/support/E2697A/high-impedance-adapter-with-500-mhz-passive-probe.html) used with the [N2873A](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/product/N2873A/passive-probe-10-1-500-mhz-1-3-m.html) has an input impedance of 10M ohm.

Look at it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRuFSF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 10M input impedance of the 1169B and the output impedance of your circuit form a voltage divider.  The input impedance of the E2697A doesn't load your circuit too badly, so you the voltage only drops a little bit.

Compare that to the 1169B:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNTIdF.png)</sup>

The much lower input impedance of the 1169B causes a much larger voltage drop.

You need to consider the impedance of your scope (and probes) as well as the impedance of the circuit you are testing.

Comment: thanks for the help.